# Connect a single level of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

This is the problem description

> Thread a binary tree, (with left, right and a sibling pointer) so that
>   all children in the user-provided level are connected - in 1 pass
>   without using space (i.e. queue etc.)

A similar problem (but not the same) is solved [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41848/join-connect-all-levels-of-binary-tree-without-any-aux-storage).
I can answer this question provided some of the constraints in the question are relaxed.

1. I can connect all levels of the tree without any extra space.
2. I can connect a specified level without extra space, provided more than a single pass is allowed
3. I can connect a specified level with extra space in a single pass.

But is there a solution to the given problem where

1. Only a single level should be connected
2. In 1 single pass
3. With no extra storage.

Comment: I assume that a normal BFS approach fails because of the "with no extra storage" requirement?

Comment: By "extra space" do you mean a queue using an iterative instead of recursive approach?

Comment: @Nick yes thats right. queue becomes extra space.

Comment: Usually using a queue in BFS is not considered extra space since you save stack by not using DFS.

Comment: Can you give an example of what this threading process would look like? Maybe it's just me, but the problem description is very unclear.

Comment: @Dukeling http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41848/join-connect-all-levels-of-binary-tree-without-any-aux-storage